Ingress configurations for UI and API
I'm trying to add kubernetes configuration for my project. Currently what happens is, I enter the / (production.local/), the GET api call to /api/courses is made so it shows the courses correctly in the /.
However, when I click one of the courses, I should get directed to the single course page and then it should show details about the course and the questions it may have. This does not happen, instead I'm still just shown the / page, but the URL do change correctly from / to /course/2.
Here is how the routes shold work:
production.local/  (url in browser)


API CALL IN THIS IN URL:

/api/courses  (GET api call in production.local/ )

After clicking one of the courses in the production.local/, the user should get directed:
production.local/course/:id  (url in browser)


POSSIBLE API CALLS MADE IN THIS URL:

/api/courses/:id  (GET api call in production.local/course/:id)

/api/questions?courseID=${courseId}&page=${page}&limit=${limit}  (GET api call in production.local/course/:id)

/api/question  (POST api call when submitting a new question)

/api/question/upvote/${questionID}  (POST api call upvoting a question)

After clicking one of the questions, the user should get directed:
prodcution.local/question/:id   (url in browser)


POSSIBLE API CALLS MADE IN THIS URL:

/api/question/:id  (GET api call in production.local/question/:id)

/api/question/${questionId}?page=${1}&limit=${limit}  (GET api call in production.local/question/:id)

/api/question/${questionId}?page=${page}&limit=${limit}  (GET api call in production.local/question/:id)

/api/answer  (POST api call when submitting a new answer)

/api/answer/upvote/${answerId}  (POST api call when upvoting an answer)

My initial nginx.conf worked just fine (in plain docker compose setup (without kuberenetes)):
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx keys_zone=astro_ssg_cache:1m inactive=5m max_size=512m;
  
  upstream qa-api {
    server qa-api:7777;
  }

  upstream qa-ui {
    server qa-ui:3000;
  }

  upstream websocket {
    server websocket:7788;
  }

  server {
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/css application/javascript application/json image/svg+xml;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    
    listen 7800;

    location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://qa-api/;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
      proxy_send_timeout 3600s;
      keepalive_timeout 3600s;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      add_header Cache-Control 'no-store';
    }

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://qa-ui;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_cache astro_ssg_cache;
      proxy_cache_key $uri;
      proxy_cache_valid 5m;
    }

    # WebSocket proxy configuration
    location /ws/ {
      proxy_pass http://websocket;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
  }
}

I tried to convert that to Ingress it to this ingress.yaml file:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2 # This rewrites the URL path
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-set-headers: "Upgrade,Connection"  # WebSocket support
spec:
  rules:
    - host: local.production
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: qa-api-service
                port:
                  number: 7777
          - path: /ws/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: websocket-service
                port:
                  number: 7788
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: qa-ui-service
                port:
                  number: 3000

I'm running kubernetes on minikube. And here are more details about the setup:
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS      AGE
pod/database-cluster-1                      1/1     Running     1 (80m ago)   12h
pod/database-cluster-2                      1/1     Running     1 (80m ago)   12h
pod/database-migration-job-tgwsq            0/1     Completed   0             12h
pod/llm-api-deployment-7cb9b96b4f-mmqlk     1/1     Running     0             62m
pod/qa-api-deployment-8b79df4d-kmmrd        1/1     Running     1 (80m ago)   12h
pod/qa-ui-deployment-77d6df9fc6-n6rzp       1/1     Running     1 (80m ago)   12h
pod/redis-deployment-5574c5f7d8-xn4db       1/1     Running     1 (80m ago)   12h
pod/websocket-deployment-646c56588c-wrv2g   1/1     Running     1 (80m ago)   12h

NAME                           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/database-cluster-any   ClusterIP      10.99.123.213    <none>        5432/TCP         12h
service/database-cluster-r     ClusterIP      10.100.84.233    <none>        5432/TCP         12h
service/database-cluster-ro    ClusterIP      10.111.123.148   <none>        5432/TCP         12h
service/database-cluster-rw    ClusterIP      10.110.118.135   <none>        5432/TCP         12h
service/llm-api-service        LoadBalancer   10.105.28.226    <pending>     7000:32089/TCP   12h
service/qa-api-service         LoadBalancer   10.106.180.233   <pending>     7777:32321/TCP   12h
service/qa-ui-service          LoadBalancer   10.97.203.95     <pending>     3000:32035/TCP   12h
service/redis-service          ClusterIP      10.102.116.81    <none>        6379/TCP         12h
service/websocket-service      ClusterIP      10.110.47.20     <none>        7788/TCP         12h

NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/llm-api-deployment     1/1     1            1           12h
deployment.apps/qa-api-deployment      1/1     1            1           12h
deployment.apps/qa-ui-deployment       1/1     1            1           12h
deployment.apps/redis-deployment       1/1     1            1           12h
deployment.apps/websocket-deployment   1/1     1            1           12h

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/llm-api-deployment-7cb9b96b4f     1         1         1       12h
replicaset.apps/qa-api-deployment-8b79df4d        1         1         1       12h
replicaset.apps/qa-ui-deployment-77d6df9fc6       1         1         1       12h
replicaset.apps/redis-deployment-5574c5f7d8       1         1         1       12h
replicaset.apps/websocket-deployment-646c56588c   1         1         1       12h

NAME                                                         REFERENCE                       TARGETS       MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/llm-api-deployment-hpa   Deployment/llm-api-deployment   cpu: 3%/10%   1         5         1          12h

NAME                               STATUS     COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/database-migration-job   Complete   1/1           6s         12h

So the project works just fine without the kubernetes. Is there a problem in my Ingress file or have I messed up something else in the process?
EDIT: I noticed that I if add rewrite-target: /, then the app will direct correctly to subpaths (for example /course/2). BUT the problem that comes with now is that the API doesn't work, because the rewrite-target set to the root instead of the second url rewrite-target: /$2. So I'm still out of luck...
So what should I do? If I could combine these two and set two rewrite-targets: rewrite-target: /$2 and rewrite-target: /, but that is not possible...
EDIT PART 2:
I realized that I can just define two different rewrite targets by setting two whole different Ingeress instances. This works for the API and the UI but I still have to figure out how to make the websocket work
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"  # Add base URL
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: local-production-tls
      hosts:
        - local.production
  rules:
    - host: local.production
      http:
        paths:
          # Static content for frontend/UI
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: qa-ui-service
                port:
                  number: 3000

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-api
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"  # Add base URL
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: local-production-tls
      hosts:
        - local.production
  rules:
    - host: local.production
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: qa-api-service
                port:
                  number: 7777


---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-websocket
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 64m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '3600'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '3600'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '3600'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: local.production
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /ws
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: websocket-service
            port:
              number: 7788

